# How to fetch DISTINCT Contact Names in Android?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am new to working with **Contacts** on Android, and am stuck on one problem. Whenever I load contacts from my phone (display name and phone number), I am getting 2 copies of each (one that must be synced to my Google Account, and the other that is stored locally on my phone).

I want to be able to use PROJECTIONS in the `contentResolver.query()` method in Android to display Contacts with distinct phone numbers.

I have tried this -

`String[] projection = new String[] {
 "Distinct"+ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
};`

but it returns an error that says
`Invalid column Distinct data1`

Is there any way to get this done using Projections, or should I resort to using a Set for eliminating duplicates ?

Comment: Try something like this:
`new String[] {"Distinct "+ ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER}` - note the space - let me know if this solves the problem.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla still getting the same error. :(